# i have this wsdl to call web service through soap usinng wsdl but this wsdl is showing some validation error

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, ldap, edirectory

```
definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            xmlns:ns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core"
         xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
        xmlns:y="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core" name="dsmlQuery"
              targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
        <types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core"
          xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
            xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
        xmlns:ns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core"
          xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
       xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:y="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core" elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
            <xsd:group name="DSMLRequests">
           <xsd:choice>
             <xsd:element name="authRequest" type="AuthRequest"/>
        <xsd:group ref="BatchRequests"/>
         </xsd:choice>
       </xsd:group>
    <xsd:group name="BatchRequests">
       <xsd:element name="abandonRequest" type="AbandonRequest"/>
      <xsd:element name="addRequest" type="AddRequest"/>
     <xsd:element name="compareRequest" type="CompareRequest"/>
         <xsd:element name="delRequest" type="DelRequest"/>
    <xsd:element name="extendedRequest" type="ExtendedRequest"/>
   <xsd:element name="modDNRequest" type="ModifyDNRequest"/>
          <xsd:element name="modifyRequest" type="ModifyRequest"/>
       <xsd:element name="searchRequest" type="SearchRequest"/>
         </xsd:choice>
       </xsd:group>
   <xsd:group name="DSMLResponses">
   <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="addResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
      <xsd:element name="authResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
     <xsd:element name="compareResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
    <xsd:element name="delResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
       <xsd:element name="errorResponse" type="ErrorResponse"/>
    <xsd:element name="extendedResponse" type="ExtendedResponse"/>
     <xsd:element name="modDNResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
   <xsd:element name="modifyResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
       <xsd:element name="searchResultDone" type="LDAPResult"/>
  <xsd:element name="searchResultEntry" type="SearchResultEntry"/>
    <xsd:element name="searchResultReference" type="SearchResultReference"/>
     </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:group>
   <xsd:element name="batchRequest" type="BatchRequest"/>
    <xsd:element name="batchResponse" type="BatchResponse"/>
   <xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="authRequest" type="AuthRequest"/>
  <xsd:group maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="BatchRequests"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:attribute name="requestID" type="RequestID" use="optional"/>
     <xsd:attribute default="sequential" name="processing" use="optional">
       <xsd:simpleType>
     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="sequential"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="parallel"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
      <xsd:attribute default="sequential" name="responseOrder" use="optional">
   <xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="sequential"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="unordered"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
       </xsd:simpleType>
     </xsd:attribute>
        <xsd:attribute default="exit" name="onError" use="optional">
               <xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value="resume"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="exit"/>
     </xsd:restriction>
         </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:complexType name="BatchResponse">
       <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:group maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="BatchResponses"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="requestID" type="RequestID" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:group name="BatchResponses">
   <xsd:choice>
     <xsd:element name="addResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
 <xsd:element name="authResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
   <xsd:element name="compareResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
<xsd:element name="delResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
   <xsd:element name="errorResponse" type="ErrorResponse"/>
        <xsd:element name="extendedResponse" type="ExtendedResponse"/>
           <xsd:element name="modDNResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
  <xsd:element name="modifyResponse" type="LDAPResult"/>
   <xsd:element name="searchResponse" type="SearchResponse"/>
       </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:group>
      <xsd:complexType name="SearchResponse">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="searchResultEntry"            
type="SearchResultEntry"/>
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="searchResultReference"           
 type="SearchResultReference"/>
<xsd:element name="searchResultDone" type="LDAPResult"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="requestID" type="RequestID" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:simpleType name="DsmlDN">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="RequestID">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="AttributeDescriptionValue">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:pattern value="((([0-2](\.[0-9]+)+)|([a-zA-Z]+([-a-zA-Z0-9])*))(;([-a-zA-Z0- 
9])+)*)"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
     <xsd:simpleType name="NumericOID">
     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:pattern value="[0-2]\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
         </xsd:simpleType>
                 <xsd:simpleType name="MAXINT">
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
    <xsd:maxInclusive value="2147483647"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
         </xsd:simpleType>
       <xsd:simpleType name="DsmlValue">
     <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:string xsd:base64Binary xsd:anyURI"/>
         </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="Control">
   <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="controlValue" type="xsd:anyType"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="type" type="NumericOID" use="required"/>
   <xsd:attribute default="false" name="criticality" type="xsd:boolean" u   s            
      </xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:complexType name="Filter">
  <xsd:group ref="FilterGroup"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:group name="FilterGroup">
 <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:choice>
   <xsd:element name="and" type="FilterSet"/>
   <xsd:element name="or" type="FilterSet"/>
  <xsd:element name="equalityMatch" type="AttributeValueAssertion"/>
  <xsd:element name="substrings" type="SubstringFilter"/>
   <xsd:element name="greaterOrEqual" type="AttributeValueAssertion"/>
  <xsd:element name="lessOrEqual" type="AttributeValueAssertion"/>
   <xsd:element name="present" type="AttributeDescription"/>
     <xsd:element name="approxMatch" type="AttributeValueAssertion"/>
   <xsd:element name="extensibleMatch" type="MatchingRuleAssertion"/>
  </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:group>
  <xsd:complexType name="FilterSet">
  <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:group maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="FilterGroup"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
       </xsd:complexType>
   < xsd:complexType name="AttributeValueAssertion">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="value" type="DsmlValue"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:attribute name="name" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="required"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="AttributeDescription">
  <xsd:attribute name="name" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="SubstringFilter">
<xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="initial" type="DsmlValue"/>
   <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="any" type="DsmlValue"/>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="final" type="DsmlValue"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="name" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="required"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="MatchingRuleAssertion">
    <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="value" type="DsmlValue"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:attribute default="false" name="dnAttributes" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional"/>
  <xsd:attribute name="matchingRule" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
  <xsd:attribute name="name" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="optional"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="DsmlMessage">
  <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="control" type="Control"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:attribute name="requestID" type="RequestID" use="optional"/>
         </xsd:complexType>
       xsd:simpleType name="LDAPResultCode">
       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="success"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="protocolError"/>
      <  xsd:enumeration value="sizeLimitExceeded"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="compareFalse"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="compareTrue"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="authMethodNotSupported"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="strongAuthRequired"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="referral"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="adminLimitExceeded"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="unavailableCriticalExtension"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="confidentialityRequired"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="saslBindInProgress"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="noSuchAttribute"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="undefinedAttributeType"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="inappropriateMatching"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="constraintViolation"/>
  <xsd:enumeration value="attributeOrValueExists"/>
  <xsd:enumeration value="invalidAttributeSyntax"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="noSuchObject"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="aliasProblem"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="invalidDNSyntax"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="aliasDerefencingProblem"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="inappropriateAuthentication"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="invalidCredentials"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="insufficientAccessRights"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="busy"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="unavailable"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="unwillingToPerform"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="loopDetect"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="namingViolation"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="objectClassViolation"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="notAllowedOnNonLeaf"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="notAllowedOnRDN"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="entryAlreadyExists"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="objectClassModsProhibited"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="affectMultipleDSAs"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="other"/>
     </xsd:restriction>
     </xsd:simpleType>
     <xsd:complexType name="ResultCode">
     <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="descr" type="LDAPResultCode" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="LDAPResult">
   <xsd:complexContent>
  <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
 <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="resultCode" type="ResultCode"/>
  <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="errorMessage" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="referral"           
      type="xsd:anyURI"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="matchedDN" type="DsmlDN" use="optional"/>
   /xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="ErrorResponse">
   <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="detail">
   <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:any/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
 </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="requestID" type="RequestID" use="optional"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="type">
<xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="notAttempted"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="couldNotConnect"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="connectionClosed"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="gatewayInternalError"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="authenticationFailed"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="unresolvableURI"/>
         <xsd:enumeration value="other"/>
         </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
              </xsd:attribute>
                 </xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:complexType name="AuthRequest">
      <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
              <xsd:attribute name="principal" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
             </xsd:extension>
             </xsd:complexContent>
       </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="AttributeDescriptions">
            <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:element name="attribute" type="AttributeDescription"/>
             </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexType name="SearchRequest">
         <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
       <xsd:complexContent>
       <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
     <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="filter" type="Filter"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="attributes" type="AttributeDescriptions"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
             <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="scope" use="required">
    <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
           <xsd:enumeration value="baseObject"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="singleLevel"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="wholeSubtree"/>
         </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:attribute>
             <xsd:attribute name="derefAliases" use="required">
           <xsd:simpleType>
         <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="neverDerefAliases"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="derefInSearching"/>
                  <xsd:enumeration value="derefFindingBaseObj"/>
           </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
          <xsd:attribute default="0" name="sizeLimit" type="MAXINT" use="optional"/>
          <xsd:attribute default="0" name="timeLimit" type="MAXINT" use="optional"/>
       <xsd:attribute default="false" name="typesOnly" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="SearchResultEntry">
     <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
<xsd:sequence>
                   <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="attr"    type="DsmlAttr"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
     </xsd:extension>
         </xsd:complexContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
             <xsd:complexType name="DsmlAttr">
           <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="value" type="DsmlValue"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="DsmlModification">
          <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="value"  type="DsmlValue"/>
</xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:attribute name="name" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="required"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="operation" use="required">
      <xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="add"/>
          <xsd:enumeration value="delete"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="replace"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:complexType name="SearchResultReference">
    <xsd:complexContent>
     <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
      <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ref" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
       </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="ModifyRequest">
     <xsd:complexContent>
     <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
      <xsd:sequence>
    < xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="modification"         type="DsmlModification"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
     </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="AddRequest">
        <xsd:attribute name="objectclass" type="top" use="Required"/>
   <xsd:attribute name="objectclass" type="person" use="Required"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="objectclass" type="organizationalPerson" use="Required"/>
     <xsd:attribute name="objectclass" type="inetorgperson" use="Required"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="givenName" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="Required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="sn" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="Required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="FullName" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="Required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="title" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="optional"/>
   <xsd:attribute name="telephoneNumber" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="mail" type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="Required"/>
    <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
   <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="attr" type="DsmlAttr"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
      </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
         </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="DelRequest">
      <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
       <xsd:complexContent>
   <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
    <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:complexType name="ModifyDNRequest">
      <xsd:complexContent>
  <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
     <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="newrdn" type="DsmlRDN" use="required"/>
   <xsd:attribute default="true" name="deleteoldrdn" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="newSuperior" type="DsmlDN" use="optional"/>
 </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="ModifyRequest">
       <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
      <xsd:attribute modification name="nspmPasswordPolicyDN" operation="Add" type="cn=Sample       
Password Policy,cn=Password Policies,cn=Security" use="Required"/>
        <xsd:attribute modification name="telephoneNumber" operation="Add"     
type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute modification name="title" operation="replace"                  
    type="AttributeDescriptionValue" use="optional"/>
         <xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="assertion" type="AttributeValueAssertion"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="dn" type="DsmlDN" use="required"/>
    </xsd:extension>
     </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="AbandonRequest">
    <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
     <xsd:attribute name="abandonID" type="RequestID" use="required"/>
      </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="ExtendedRequest">
      <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="DsmlMessage">
      <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="requestName" type="NumericOID"/>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="requestValue" type="xsd:anyType"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:complexType name="ExtendedResponse">
     xsd:complexContent>
     <xsd:extension base="LDAPResult">
      <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="responseName" type="NumericOID"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="response" type="xsd:anyType"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
       </types>
    <message name="dsmlRequest">
    <part name="batchRequest" element="ns:batchRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="dsmlResponse">
   <part name="batchResponse" element="ns:batchResponse"/>
    </message>
     <portType name="dsmlSoap">
      <operation name="directoryRequest">
       <input message="ns:dsmlRequest"/>
   <output message="ns:dsmlResponse"/>
       </operation>
      </portType>
              <binding name="dsmlQuerySoap" type="ns:dsmlSoap">
       <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name="directoryRequest">
   <soap:operation soapAction="#batchRequest"/>
    <input>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
       </input>
       <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
       </output>
       </operation>
     </binding>
      <service name="dsmlQueryService">
         <port name="dsmlSoapQuery" binding="ns:dsmlQuerySoap">
     <soap:address location="http://10.18.26.56:18080/novell-dsml/stream"/>
          </port >
        </service>
     </definitions>
```

This wsdl showing error while opening in soapUI.i want this WSDl to launch webservices through java application .please help me to solve it and i am new to this WSDL i am not able to find any errors .its throwing some validation error

Comment: i want to access my e directory using soap Ui but i have this wsdl but it showing some validation error and malformed request and its not connecting

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI is giving an error -

> org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException:
>   error:   does not close tag

These are some of the messed up elements which I can find in your wsdl, correct these and test again if the error is resolved.

> **definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"**
>
> **xsd:attribute default="false" name="criticality" type="xsd:boolean" u   s**
>
> **xsd:simpleType name="LDAPResultCode">**
>
> **xsd:complexContent>**

P.S. - there may be more errors in the wsdl but these are the ones which I got in the first sight, look at the wsdl carefully.